# Receive http request

Tags: django, python-3.x, dictionary, request, httpresponse

CLIENT:
I sent this http request, code:

```
import requests
payload =  {'data': [{'name': 'pippo', 'age':'7'}, {'name':'luca', 'age':'12'}]}
r = requests.post("http://127.0.0.1:8000", data=payload)
print(r.url)
```

Server Django. code views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt

@csrf_exempt
def home(request):
    context = {'request_method': request.method}
    if request.method == 'POST':
        context['request_payload'] = request.POST.dict()
        post_data = request.POST
        print(post_data) 
        for key, value in post_data.items():
            for subvalue in value:
                print{key, subvalue}

    if request.method == 'GET':
        context['request_payload'] = request.GET.dict()
    return render(request, 'main/index.html', context)
```

when i do execute. Django i not receive data of send client.
My result in `print(post_data)`on django are : `<QueryDict: {'data': ['name', 'age', 'name', 'age']}>`

I would like to extract this:
{'name': 'pippo', 'age':'7'} 
{'name':'luca', 'age':'12'}

How can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't data that can be easily represented in form-encoded format. You need to send JSON.

```
r = requests.post("http://127.0.0.1:8000", json=payload)
```

and parse it in the view:

```
post_data = json.loads(request.body)
```